# MySQL Nested Select and IFNULL Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql

need help on a MySQL query, can't seem to figure out how to correctly write this statement. I am trying to nest a select in an insert statment and ifnull is also used.

```
INSERT INTO vo (vo_id, agreement_id, serial_no, vo_date, vo_status) 
VALUES (NULL, '3',  (SELECT IFNULL(max(serial_no),1) FROM vo WHERE agreement_id = '3'), CURDATE(), 'Open')
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!

EDIT: Error i got in mysql is : #1093 - You can't specify target table 'vo' for update in FROM clause

Comment: just added the error in an edit thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of this error by wrapping your subquery in another subquery without `WHERE` clause :

```
INSERT INTO vo 
(vo_id, agreement_id, serial_no, vo_date, vo_status) 
VALUES 
(NULL, '3',  (SELECT x.* 
             FROM (SELECT IFNULL(max(serial_no),1) 
                   FROM vo 
                   WHERE agreement_id = '3'
                  ) x), CURDATE(), 'Open')
```

Comment: @user3448267 : Have you succeeded?

Comment: yes this works perfectly, but I am having trouble understanding this syntax. what does the x.* and x in the nested statement do actually?

Comment: @user3448267 : it is an alias for the retrieved by subquery table(In some RDBMS alias for subqueries is required).

Comment: x is an alias for subquery to be as table x .

Comment: thanks everyone will have to read up abit more about these aliases

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   INSERT INTO vo (vo_id, agreement_id, serial_no, vo_date, vo_status) 
   VALUES (NULL, '3', (SELECT * from  (SELECT IFNULL(max(serial_no),1) FROM vo WHERE agreement_id = '3')t), CURDATE(), 'Open')
```

Comment: thanks, this works too but I could only mark an answer!